# R package dependency issue in building docker image for shiny app

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image for my shiny app.  My docker image is 'successfully' built, but cannot be started on localhost.  Checking the logs in image building process, I saw error messages like below:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘leafpop’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/leafpop’
..........

1: In install.packages(c("remotes", "shiny", "shinythemes", "shinydashboard",  :>
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(c("remotes", "shiny", "shinythemes", "shinydashboard",  :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(c("remotes", "shiny", "shinythemes", "shinydashboard",  :
  installation of package ‘leafpop’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like it has some package dependency issue. seems like package `leafpop` is dependent on `sf`. Not sure about package `units`......

My question is:

1. How I should modify my Dockerfile to solve this dependency issues? I guess this is also a general question....
2. I waited quite a while for the image building process to complete.  How should I modify my Dockerfile, so that when some package installation failed, it stops the building process? just to save my time.

my Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev

RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('remotes', 'shinythemes','shinydashboard','shinyWidgets','shinyjs', 'rlang','scales','DT','lubridate', 'plotly',  'leaflet', 'leafpop', 'visNetwork', 'wordcloud2', 'arules'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('nik01010/dashboardthemes')"


COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

EXPOSE 80

COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you install something that references ubuntu 12.04. That's 8 years old now, and the rocker images are based on debian 10, which came out last year.

Answer (score 2):

The error logs will usually tell you what the problem was. In the case of the `units` package, a system library was not found, namely `libudunits2.so`. The error message even tells you how to install it.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because the base image is based on a debian image, use the `apt` package, which is `libudunits2-dev`. Installing that package with `apt-get` fixes this error.

The error relating to `sf` is as follows:

```
* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: gcc
configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sf’
cat: leafpop.out: No such file or directory

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpmvJxnC/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(c("remotes", "shinythemes", "shinydashboard",  :
  installation of one or more packages failed,
  probably ‘sf’, ‘leafpop’
```

The main error there is that `gdal-config` is not found or not executable. After some googling, we find that the `libgdal-dev` package provides `gdal-config`. Installing that with `apt-get` solves that problem.

In the future, I recommend debugging by trying to build the container interactively. Then write the correct commands in a Dockerfile. It's easier to debug interactively than to iteratively modify your Dockerfile.

---

Regarding your second question, `install.packages` accepts an `Ncpus` argument, which will compile the packages in parallel (if the packages support that). This can significantly decrease your build times.

```
install.packages(... Ncpus=6)  # for example
```